# Problems in fetching data using Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I saw a tutorial on YouTube from Firebase showing how to fetch data between firestore and swiftui (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6u3AnOKZd0). Here's the code that I copied exactly the same:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import Foundation

class BooksViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var books = [Book]()`
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData(){
        db.collection("books").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No results")
                return
            }
            self.books = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Book in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let author = data["author"] as? String ?? ""
                let pages = data["pages"] as? Int ?? 0
                
                return Book(title: title, author: author, numberOfPages: pages)
          
            }
        }
    }

}

struct Book: Identifiable{
    var id:String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var numberOfPages: Int

}

struct Search: View {
   @ObservedObject private var viewModel = BooksViewModel()
  
    var body: some View {
        
        List(viewModel.books){ book in
            VStack{
                Text(book.title).font(.headline)
                Text(book.author).font(.subheadline)
                Text("\(book.numberOfPages) pages").font(.subheadline)                  
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that nothing is being displayed.
In Firestore, I have the "books" collection, and inside, for each automatic ID, I have a title, an author and a pages.
When I display the List without Firestore (as he shows in the beginning of the video) it works fine. But, when I connect it to Firestore, it shows nothing. But the thing is that it may be connect as in "Use", inside "Cloud Firestore" in Firebase, there was a spike of 86 readings, 15 recordings and 8 exclusions. Anyone know how to solve it?

11.0 Beta Big Sur
12.1 Xcode

What appears on console:
2020-10-22 08:21:35.875930-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811559] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.sigma2'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
2020-10-22 08:21:36.176284-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811496] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2020-10-22 08:21:37.083782-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811559] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2020-10-22 08:21:37.172409-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811559] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see "")
2020-10-22 08:21:39.418386-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811558] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-22 08:21:42.157064-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811560] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-10-22 08:21:42.157878-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811560] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist

Updated console information:
2020-10-22 11:18:52.062418-0300 aplicativo[49379:2031899] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2020-10-22 11:18:53.463035-0300 aplicativo[49379:2031919] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2020-10-22 11:18:53.504736-0300 aplicativo[49379:2031919] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see "goo.gl/RfcP7r")
2020-10-22 11:18:55.710625-0300 aplicativo[49379:2031900] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-22 11:19:03.453691-0300 aplicativo[49379:2031891] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-10-22 11:19:03.556959-0300 aplicativo[49379:2031891] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist

Comment: What is printing out of the console when you try to do this?

Comment: Try cloning the repo at https://github.com/peterfriese/bookspine (which is the basis for the video) and see if you run into the same issue.

Comment: @purebreadd a added it in the question

Comment: Mateus, if you've been able to resolve this issue using the help we provided here and on the repo you shared on GitHub, I'd recommend either accepting one of the answers that helped you resolve the issue(s), write an answer yourself, or closing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was fine, the problem was in Firebase Security Rules.

Here's what I used to get it working:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
        request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 11, 25);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good to hear. Keep in mind that your database will be wide open for reads and writes for anyone (!), at least until November 25th 2020. Consider implementing proper Security Rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started to keep your users' data safe.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `books` assignment on main queue, like

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.books = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Book in
        let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
        
        let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
        let author = data["author"] as? String ?? ""
        let pages = data["pages"] as? Int ?? 0
        
        return Book(title: title, author: author, numberOfPages: pages)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the logs, that's helpful.

The first message log message indicates there is an issue with the bundle ID:

```
2020-10-22 08:21:35.875930-0300 aplicativo[38475:1811559] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.sigma2'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
```

Essentially, the bundle ID of the app doesn't match with the bundle ID in the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. Make sure the bundle IDs match. The [Firebase Getting Started with iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) page in the docs shows how to register an iOS app with your Firebase project.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Right after I added the console information I saw it, and immediately downloaded the right GoogleService-info.plist. But, the problem still insist to happen. I'll add in the question the updated information that is on console.